# Characterization of torus $I/\mathbb{Z}^{d}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-spaces

The quotient space $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ be defined by the set of all equivalence classes with respect to the equivalence relation $x \sim y \iff x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$. This quotient space is then proved to be the set $\mathbb{S}^{1} := \{[x]: x \in [0,1)\}$. Analogously, $\mathbb{R}^{d}/\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^{d}$.

Now, let $L \in \mathbb{R}$ be an even number and consider the set $I = [-L/2,L/2]^{d}$. In an analogous way, the set $I\subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is, by definition this is the set of all equivalence classes $x \sim y \iff x-y \in \mathbb{Z}^{3}$ for $x,y \in I$.

What is the characterization of $I/\mathbb{Z}^{3}$? I mean,what set does it represent as a "subset of" $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Comment: If $L\geq 1$, you will still get $(\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z})^d$ as a set, and also as a topological space. As $I$ does not have an additive structure, the quotient does not a priori have one either, though you can of course just steal the one from $(\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z})^d$.

If $L<1$, the equivalence classes are all one point sets, i.e. $I/\Bbb{Z}^d = I$, so topologically you just get a line, and you have no obvious group structure.

I don't understand what you mean by represented as a "subset of $\Bbb{R}^d$". How is $(\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z})^d$ viewed as such a subset to begin with?